# Jekyll - Wrap variables

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Working with Jekyll, I have the following variable : {{ page.categories | category_links }}

I would like each result (each categories) to be wrapped in a li tag. 
How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to show the categories as an unordered list:

```
<ul>
{% for category in page.categories %}
  <li>{{ category }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```